# Should we allow a question that asks for list of references throughout a series?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

An example would be this question:

[What are the original memes mentioned in Steins;Gate?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/14347/what-are-the-original-memes-mentioned-in-steinsgate)

I think it would be nice to have a collaborative effort to answer such a question. The scope is 24 episodes, plus an OVA, plus a movies. As long as the series is reasonably sized, it can possibly be answer through collaborative effort.

Possible problem would be low quality answers/partial answers. While it can be solved by adding a single answer and close the question, getting people to edit the answer is hard.

Even with those downsides, I think having such question would increase the value of our site.

Comment: This discussion is more of allowing a question that can be considered to be broad to be answered via collaborative effort.

Comment: It has a defined answer and it is reasonably scoped, I think. We did decide to allow in-universe list questions, and IIRC this falls under that blanket.

Comment: @キルア: I ask this, since the question in question (pun intended) has accumulated 3 close votes.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with asking. I voted to leave open; it would be nice if those voters would give their opinions.

Comment: If the question is about a single series, to the best of my knowledge it's still covered by http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/348/what-is-the-status-of-list-questions-on-this-site.

Comment: I don't think it's reasonably scoped. There is no way to tell that a list of this sort is complete as a show could reference just about anything, just as http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4129/what-are-all-the-cross-references-in-binbo-gami-ga was closed

Comment: I didn't think there were that many memes in Steins;Gate. Not as much cultural references as Binbougami Ga.  I probably should have clarified that I wanted to know if there's any corresponding Japanese memes to the English translated memes and only the ones that are English translated.

Comment: @ToshinouKyouko I fully disagree. Not only do I think the question you linked is a bad example, given your answer, but the meme base in *Steins;Gate* is reasonably small.

Comment: The question was closed just after I answered it, you can see how many series there were in my answer so it was rightly closed - I cannot be sure I have all the references correct.

Comment: My issue is really with the vaguity of 'meme', although you say the list is a small enough

Comment: I agree that the linked question qualifies under the previously-agreed-upon rules for lists that Logan M linked to above (it is specific, objective, reasonably scoped at 24 episodes/OAV/movie/ONA w/o a ton of memes included, and not prone to change), so I voted to re-open the question.